# terratest receive error (variable of type *string) as type string in argument while read the cloudwatch log stream

Tags: go, terraform, terratest

I'm very new to golang, so I'm trying to follow: [terratest_code-base](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/tree/master/modules/aws) while buidling my test to read the cw log stream.

```
terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
            // The path to where our Terraform code is located to give the folder name
            TerraformDir: "../../",

            // Variables to pass to our Terraform code using -var options
            Vars: map[string]interface{}{
                "dynamo_db_table_name": expectedTableName,
                "token": token,
                "aws_region": awsRegion,
                "access_key": accessKey,
                "secret_key": secretKey,
                "environment": environment,
            },

            // Environment variables to set when running Terraform
            EnvVars: map[string]string{
                "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": awsRegion,
                "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": accessKey,
                "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": secretKey,
                "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": token,
            },
            // Backend config to create state file in S3
            BackendConfig: map[string]interface{}{
                "bucket": bucketName,
                "key":    key,
                "region": awsRegion,
            },
        })
    // At the end of the test, run `terraform destroy` to clean up any resources that were created
    defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    // This will run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and fail the test if there are any errors
    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

client := aws.NewCloudWatchLogsClient(t, awsRegion)
    cw_main_log_group_prefix := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "main_cloudwatch_log_name")

    groups, err := client.DescribeLogGroups(&cloudwatchlogs.DescribeLogGroupsInput{LogGroupNamePrefix: &cw_main_log_group_prefix})
    // cw_prefix_not_exist_msg := fmt.Sprintf("CW Log group %s does not exists", cw_main_log_group_prefix)
    if err != nil {
        assert.Error(t, errors.New("Error in "))
    }

    if len(groups.LogGroups) < 1 {
             assert.Error(t, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("No log group found for %s", cw_main_log_group_prefix)))
    }

    group := groups.LogGroups[0]
    fmt.Println(group)
    streams, err := client.DescribeLogStreams(&cloudwatchlogs.DescribeLogStreamsInput{
            LogGroupName: group.LogGroupName,
            Descending:   awsSDK.Bool(true),
            OrderBy:      awsSDK.String("LastEventTime"),
    })

    if len(streams.LogStreams) < 1 {
          assert.Error(t, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("No log streams found for %s", cw_main_log_group_prefix)))
    }

    stream := streams.LogStreams[0]
     message, err := aws.GetCloudWatchLogEntriesE(t, awsRegion, stream.LogStreamName, cw_main_log_group_prefix)
```

I'm getting below error:

```
cannot use stream.LogStreamName (variable of type *string) as type string in argument to aws.GetCloudWatchLogEntriesE
```

as the response from describeLogstream has string attribute called `LogStreamName`

My question is how to fix this?

can anyone suggest me how to follow carry out the test?
only thing it prints is `fmt.Println(group)`

Comment: change the param `stream.LogStreamName` to `*(stream.LogStreamName)`  at latest line?

Comment: It sounds as if the error message is merely requesting that you dereference the pointer in the method parameters because it expects a `string` type. Have you tried that?